# MS Access VBA Refresh Only Visible Items

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image: Refresh]

Can anyone tell me the VBA command in Access to refresh only the visible items in the dataset? This is the equivalent of clicking the refresh button shown on the ribbon. It has the benefit of keeping the scroll position and not refreshing the entire dataset. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using information from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627337(v=office.12).aspx

```
commandbars.FindControl(ID:=1020).Execute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recordset or querydef of the records that you want to  show in a form and then use the command Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow to show the live refresh in the database.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your suggestion doesn't answer the question.